# Java program to retrieve thousands of related *complete* sentences from Google Search results

Tags: java

I'm doing deep linguistic analysis so I'm in need of large number of *complete* sentences related to certain keywords.

Therefore, I'm thinking of retrieve thousands of results from Google, and I also need a way to customize the Google Search result snippet so that it will give me the *complete* sentence around the keyword.

Two problems:
1. how to retrieve thousands of results from Google? I heard there is a limit of 100 per query
2. how to customize search snippet so that Google returns a *complete* sentence around the keyword for each query?

Do anybody have some hint for doing this? Any comments are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For problem number 2, what about parsing each of the result pages and pulling the complete sentence from the original source.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely works, but will takes a large amount of time to retrieve docs from original source. Since I need thousands of sentences for each query, and will do it for large amount of queries. so it would be almost infeasible to do so.

Comment: Had you thought of approaching Google about an API to achieve this efficiently?  Most of these requests violate the TOS of the site in question.